# How to establish communication between Client and the Server application developed in C++ Via JSON

Tags: c++, json, server, client, non-web

I asked to develop a client server application Communicating via JSON messages.

I developed an application communicating via string messages. I do wanna include JSON in the place of string.

I have no Idea about JSON at all. It's very new for me.

Can any of you help me out where to start and where to end up with.

Comment: Looks like what you need: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

Comment: @MartinZhai I gone through it I don't know how to Use the libraries as well. AS i said before I don't know noting about JSON.

Comment: First of all, JSON is a text message and is easy to learn it, check this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp. If you want send and receive text message in c++ you need to set the size of message before send it. It suggestion is because you don't say what kind oh channel you will use, like sockets or JMS, etc. Think about a protocolo which wraps the Json message. Once you have the whole message you can use a json parser. Check the ISO model to see how layers are communicated between them.

Comment: I share you a lib to parse JSON, developed in c++, it could help you: https://github.com/jorgemedra/JSONLib

Comment: Thanks a lot sir